# vb.net - Await requires that the type 'Task' have a suitable GetAwaiter Method

Tags: vb.net

Iam trying to make unzip program but when i start unzip fuction the program got freeze or some lag i tried to lose async but i got error: Await requires that the type 'Task' have a suitable GetAwaiter Method.
This is my code

```
Private Async Sub PictureBox8_MouseClick(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles PictureBox8.MouseClick
    Dim worker As New Task(startUnZip())
    worker.Start()
    Await worker
    MsgBox("Done.")
End Sub
```

Also my startunZip() code is:

```
 Public Function startUnZip()
    IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(outputFolder)


    Dim output As Object = shObj.NameSpace((outputFolder))


    Dim input As Object = shObj.NameSpace((inputZip))

    output.CopyHere((input.Items), 20)

    Return 100
End Function
```

Thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Firstly, turn `Option Strict On` and then fix the issues it flags, including specifying the return type of your function.

As for the question:

```
Private Async Sub PictureBox8_MouseClick(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles PictureBox8.MouseClick
    Await Task.Run(AddressOf startUnZip)
    MsgBox("Done.")
End Sub
```

Comment: Where can i make Option Strict On - because i got Option Strict On disallows implicit conversions from 'Point' to 'Size'

Comment: This is the code 
Dim loc As Point
    Private Sub PictureBox2_MouseDown(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles PictureBox2.MouseDown
        If e.Button = Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left Then
            loc = e.Location
        End If
    End Sub
    Private Sub PictureBox2_MouseMove(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles PictureBox2.MouseMove
        If e.Button = Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left Then
            Me.Location += e.Location - loc
        End If
    End Sub

Comment: If you're getting a message telling you that `Option Strict On` doesn't allow something then you already have `Option Strict On`. What you need to do is fix the code that it is telling you is not allowed. The things that it disallows are all about proper use of data types. If there's an error, you not using data types properly. If a `Size` is expected then use a `Size`, not a `Point`. Don't sit on your hands and wait to have everything explained to you. Do some research about `Option Strict`. Also, don't post long code snippets in comments or any code snippets unformatted. Too hard to read.

Comment: Run' is not a member of 'Task'

Comment: What version of .NET are you targeting?

Comment: Iam using .NET v4

Comment: `Task.Run` was added in .NET 4.5. Try `Task.Factory.StartNew` instead.

Comment: I gave you code that works in .NET 4.5+ and I told you how to change it to work in .NET 4.0. If you can't copy, paste and edit then you've got bigger issues.

Comment: `ConfigureAwait(False)`??? Why would want to continue using the Task's thread after the Await?

Comment: I agree with TnTinMn. `ConfigureAwait(False)` is not something I'ld use in WinForms. `Await` captures the Contex just fine.

Comment: @TnTinMn, fair point. I've been writing so much async service layer code recently that I think I put that in there without thinking. I've edited the answer.